# React component to hooks, how to migrate redux actions triggered by redux-thunk?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

action code works with `redux-thunk`

```js
export const theAction = (param) => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(someAction(param));
}
```

Old component working code:

```js
class MyComponent extends Component {
...
    render() => <Child theAction={theAction}/>
}

...
export default connect(stateToProps, {theAction})(MyComponent);
```

New hooks, but the `theAction` is not being triggered

```js
function MyComponent(props){
    return <Child theAction={theAction}/>
}
```

I have also tried (shooting in the dark)

```
function MyComponent(props){
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const theActionDispatch = () => dispatch(theAction)

    return <Child theAction={theActionDispatch}/>
}
```

Comment: inside `Child` how you called `theAction`, `this.props.theAction` instead of`props.theAction` ? (lol)

Comment: `theAction` triggered or not is `redux-thunk` irrelevant, so please check your code where `theAction` invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If many children get this action I'd use useCallback as well:

```
const theActionDispatch = React.useCallback(
  (...args) => dispatch(theAction(...args)),
  [dispatch]
);
```